Looking for ideas to empirically distinguish two similar calcium compounds
I am looking for ideas to empirically distinguish two similar calcium compounds: calcium metaphosphate $\ce{Ca(PO3)2}$ and tricalcium phosphate $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$ commonly known as calcium orthophosphate.
Both are white powders. They are not evenly ground so the air between the crystals makes it hard to precisely measure their volume for a density calculation.  I could not measure their melting point either because they seem to decompose or react with air at high temperatures (I have no argon to displace the air). Besides, I could not find the published m.p. for both of them.
References:
Structure of calcium metaphosphate Ca(PO3)2 by W. Rothammel, H. Burzlaff and R. Specht

George Robinson, Qualitative or visual tests cannot distinguish them only instrumental techniques like X-ray diffraction/ FTIR/Raman spectroscopies would be able to distinguish them.

@ACR:  I was afraid of that and hoping for some kind of solubility test or clever reagent test.

George Robinson, You will have to search classical Analytical Chemistry books from pre-1970s to 1900s Those books most likely have it. What is the purpose of this analysis?

Infrared or Raman should distinguish between the two, at least tell that the samples are the same or different. the decomposition in air is strange, possibly water? Try drying the samples. Lange's Handbook lists both with different MP, the meta should melt in a Bunsen flame.

I would try to melt them using a propane blowtorch. Calcium methaphosphate melts at around 1000 Celsium, which is withing capabilities of a hand blowtorch without supply of pressured air or oxygen. Orthophosphate melts at around 1500 Celsium. Furthermore, methaphospates tend to form glasses, which means they tend to form viscous melts around their melting point.

You can distinguish the compounds chemically. From Vogel Qualitative Analysis, 5th ed.:


Good job Nilay. I was thinking Vogel must have it but wasn't sure which one. Vogel had written plenty of books in analytical chemistry in the 60s-70s. Still, they are one of the best references for classical techniques.

All these tests must be valid for soluble ortho, metaphosphates, but the question is, is the calcium salt soluble to begin with?

The crystalline Calcium Metaphosphate is insoluble in water.  Also, I was unable to dissolve it in 10% acetic acid and 30% HCl but I think the hydrochloric acid has gone yellowish. I can reverify it with proper controls, if it is significant.  I can try it with stronger acids (e.g.: nitric, sulfuric) if no toxic phosporous compounds will be released.

The Albumin test seems interesting but is the acetic acid insolubility a show-stopper ?  If "not", can bovine milk-derived Albumin be used ?

...and that Copper Sulphate solution is a solution of CuSO4 in what solvent ?

...water is understood if not specified.

I am by no means an analytical chemist, so just a thought.
Orthocalcium phosphate appears to be triclinic, while according to the source you provide calcium metaphosphate is monoclinic. If you have access to an optical microscope, you might be able to see single crystallites that have a characteristic shape.
